# Having problem on live server seems bootstarp is not working on live server

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

my website works normally when I open it on local but it becomes distorted when I launch it on a live server it seems that all bootstrap styles are not working on live server I'm not able to understand the reason behind this.
please help me if anyone knows the reason behind this.
I'm sharing the code of front page please see it-:
and the screenshots of website working with or without live server:

[screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAGnJ.jpg)

[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLrVA.jpg)

[screenshot-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzNkS.jpg)

code-:I had removed some unessential part of code so that it can be read effectively.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\abhay agnihotri\Desktop\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap.min.css">
            <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

            <title> </title>
        </head>
    <body >
        <nav class="  navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <div  class="on" id="content container alpha">
              <span class="slide">
                  <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                      <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                  </a>   
              </span>
              <div class=" nav d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column">
                <div id="menu" class="nav va" style="scroll-behavior: unset;">
                  <a href="#" class="close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>  
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class=" col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="some1 a"><a>HOME</a><br> </div>
                  <div class="some2 b"><a class="some2 b" href="aboutus.html" style="text-decoration: none;">ABOUT</a><br> </div>
                  <div class="some3 c"><a class="some3 c" href="team.html" style="text-decoration: none;">TEAM</a><br> </div>
                  <div class="some4 d"><a class="some4 d" href="#ourmenu" style="text-decoration: none;">OURMENU</a><br> </div>
                  <div class="some5 e"><a class="some5 e" href="gallery.html" style="text-decoration: none;">GALLERY</a><br> </div>
                  <div class="some6 f"><a class="some6 f" href="contact.html" style="text-decoration: none;">CONTACT</a><br> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-0"></div>
                  </div> 
             </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          </a>
          <div class="main">
          <img src="cart2.png"  class="cart img-fluid">
          <input type="text" class="text-center item" id="inc" value="0"></input>
          </div>
          <img src="add2.png"  class="add img-fluid" >
        </nav>
        <header>
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators ">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" ></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item z active car carss img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item van men img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item maruti women img-fluid "></div>
          </div>
          </div>
     </header>
     <div class="container">
      <div class=" text-center row" style="margin-top:-660px;">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-0">
          <div class=" text-light col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
          <h1 class="head">PIZZERIA</h1>
          <h3 class="text-center foot">SPICYFOOD</h3>
          <img  class="logo"src="kn.png" width=50 height=50 class="media">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-0"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
     </div>

              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
              <script src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"> </script> 
              <script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"> </script> 
              <script src= "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: LOOK THAT: <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\abhay agnihotri\Desktop\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Actual CDN BS4 CSS is: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: @BossCOTIGA - you have certainly found the issue :)  I would recommend posting it as an answer so that the user can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginner error :)

You search for the CSS path on your local PC
Try the Bootstap 4 CDN link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And JS CDN from:

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#js
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't upload bootstrap css file correctly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\abhay agnihotri\Desktop\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap.min.css">
```

Indicate file correctly:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="...\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap.min.css">
```